# Aiogram 2. Как заблокировать пользователя в боте, чтобы он не мог ему писать, ну или как минимум бот его игнорировал?

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

Никак не могу реализовать блокировку пользователя по инлайн кнопке. Заранее всем спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Это как? Как это должно выглядеть поэтапно?

Comment: У меня бот для заявок, весь код для заявок с кнопками для одобрения/отклонения заявок сделан. Мне нужно всего-то банить пользователя, чтобы он больше не мог взаимодействовать с ботом.

Comment: И что вам мешает сохранить идентификатор пользователя и игнорировать update'ы от него?

Comment: Я не знаю как это сделать